"Unsupported TFLite Operator Error in qnn-tflite-converter"
enter image description hereThe error message indicates that when running the qnn-tflite-converter tool with a TensorFlow Lite (TFLite) model file, it encountered an unsupported TFLite operator with code 127. This error occurs because the version of the fbs schema being used does not support this particular operator. The qnn-tflite-converter tool is a part of Qualcomm's AI Stack and is used to convert TFLite models to another format. To resolve this issue, it's necessary to either update the fbs schema to support the operator or to find an alternative approach to handle this specific operator within the conversion process.
I attempted to convert a TensorFlow Lite (TFLite) model using the qnn-tflite-converter tool, expecting it to successfully convert the model without encountering any errors. However, during the conversion process, an error occurred indicating that an unsupported TFLite operator with code 127 was encountered. This error was due to the version of the fbs schema being used not supporting this particular operator. As a result, the conversion process failed, preventing the successful conversion of the TFLite model.

The operator that is used in the tflite model is incompatible with the QNN format that the converter generates. You would need to create custom operators. See: the following.

Thanks for your question.
Currently the TensorFlow Lite (TFlite) is not supported by Qualcomm AI Engine Direct (QNN). If you would like, can you please share the model file.
In the meantime, you can create your own custom package to handle this issue.
Here is a link for the Qualcomm AI Engine Direct (QNN) op package:
https://docs.qualcomm.com/bundle/publicresource/topics/80-63442-50/generating_op_packages.htm
